# Trying to get margins right

Tags: margins, geometry

I need my document look like as the one in the following screenshot:

[image]

Right now, mine look like it’s right shifted. I’m using book class.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{hmargin={3cm, 6cm}}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[pagestyles, explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\raggedleft}
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}%
    \rlap{ \resizebox{!}{1.5cm}{\thechapter} \rule{5cm}{1.5cm}}}
  {10pt}{\Huge#1}

\titleformat{name = \chapter, numberless}[block]
 {\normalfont\Large\filleft}
 {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitle}
}%
 {10pt}{\Huge#1\rlap{\hskip0.5em\color{lightgray!50!}\rule[-0.5cm]{6cm}{1.5cm}}}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introduction}
\setcounter{chapter}{2}
\chapter{Implementation}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmargin defines the left and the right margin. Since you used different values here, your text lock is not centered with respect to the physical page.

Comment: @leandriis So should I use 3cm,3cm instead for get the page centered?

Comment: hmargin=3cm should work according to the geometry package manual.

Comment: Yes  but you shouldn't  forget the binding-offset.

Comment: @Bernard Could you expand on the binding thing?

Comment: It is the horizontal space reserved for binding (usually from 0.5 to 1 cm), which should not  be counted  in the paper width for the calculations of the margins

Comment: @Bernard I've got it like this in my tex document: `\geometry{bindingoffset=1cm}                `

Comment: In this case, it's fine!

Comment: @Bernard I reduced it to 0.5 :), it looks better. Thanks!